# Resize all images in a div

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="test"><img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
<div class="test"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var max = 100;
var img = $('div.test img');
if (img.width() > max) {
    img.width = max;
}
```

I would like all images found within the `.test` class `<div>` to be rescaled to the maximum width defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var max = 100;
$('div.test img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > max) {
        $(this).width(max);
    }
});
```

...will loop through all of the images, testing and (possibly) setting the width of each in turn.

Alternative solution:

```
var max = 100;
$('div.test img').width(function(i,w) {
    return Math.min(w, max);
});
```

Further reading:

- the [`.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- the [`.width()` method](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 1):

As simple as that:

```
$('div.test img').css({'max-width' : '100px'});
```

Comment: I guess u can write it as `css({'max-width' : '100%'});`